# Debugging FeatureClassToFeatureClass giving ERROR 000732?

Tags: arcpy, file-geodatabase, error-000732

I get this Error when trying to run the FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>   
>       arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(inFeatures, outLocation, outFeatureclass)   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\conversion.py", line 1675, in
>   FeatureClassToFeatureClass
>       raise e ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000732: Input Features: Dataset Parcel_Owners does not exist or
>   is not supported Failed to execute (FeatureClassToFeatureClass).

This is my code:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "D:\Users\ShawnO\Desktop\PythonExercizes\Parcel_Ownership_update_model\Parcels.gdb"
inFeatures = "D:\Users\ShawnO\Desktop\PythonExercizes\Parcel_Ownership_update_model\Parcels.gdb\Parcel_Owners"
outLocation = "D:\Users\ShawnO\Desktop\PythonExercizes\Parcel_Ownership_update_model\Old_Parcel_Owner\Old_Parcel_Owners.gdb"
outFeatureclass = "old_owners"
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(inFeatures, outLocation, outFeatureclass)
```

What is wrong with my variable inFeatures? I know that a feature class table consists of more than one file but examples on the internet had the name of the Featureclass as an acceptable input.

Answer (score 4):

Try changing:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = "D:\Users\ShawnO\Desktop\PythonExercizes\Parcel_Ownership_update_model\Parcels.gdb"
inFeatures = "D:\Users\ShawnO\Desktop\PythonExercizes\Parcel_Ownership_update_model\Parcels.gdb\Parcel_Owners"
outLocation = "D:\Users\ShawnO\Desktop\PythonExercizes\Parcel_Ownership_update_model\Old_Parcel_Owner\Old_Parcel_Owners.gdb"
```

to:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = r"D:\Users\ShawnO\Desktop\PythonExercizes\Parcel_Ownership_update_model\Parcels.gdb"
inFeatures = "Parcel_Owners"
outLocation = r"D:\Users\ShawnO\Desktop\PythonExercizes\Parcel_Ownership_update_model\Old_Parcel_Owner\Old_Parcel_Owners.gdb"
```

The main problem is that you need to escape the backslash which is a special character to Python.  There are several ways to do this but putting an `r` before any string containing a pathname with one or more backslashes is my preferred.